# Crop all pdf file pictures created with asymptote

Tags: graphics, asymptote

In my educational work I often need to create documents containing a lot of pictures created separately with `asymptote` package then included when needed with `\includegraphics`.

Often I find more appropriate to  create with asymptote a single pdf file containing some related pictures each one being on in its own page.

Most of the time this works fine except when the pictures are of very different sizes because  then I am obliged  to manually trim the smaller ones to avoid  wide whites spaces. This is due to the fact that in the pdf file all the pages are of the same size.

Ideally the solution would be to get a pdf file whose pages are of different sizes. Each page fits its content. But I don't know if it is doable with `asymptote`.

```
// asymptote file example.asy
   unitsize(cm);
   path p1=unitsquare;
   path p2=circle((-5,0),1);
   draw(scale(1,5)*p1);
   newpage();
   draw(p2);
// end of example.asy
```

- 

```
   % latex file
   \documentclass[10pt]{article}
   \usepackage{lipsum}
   \usepackage{graphicx}

   \begin{document}
      \lipsum[11]
      \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[page=1]{example.pdf}
      \end{center}
      \lipsum[11]
      \begin{center}
         \includegraphics[page=2]{example.pdf}
      \end{center}
      \lipsum[11]
   \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be an option to add to Asymptote code inline (for example with https://www.ctan.org/pkg/asypictureb)? That would solve the page size issue.

Comment: @Marjin I generally use asymptote separately  to create many figures in the same asy file.

Comment: I understand, but maybe for this use case it would be worth to consider to put the code inline in the `.tex` file? Unless you plan to reuse the same figure many times in different documents, putting the figures in the document directly seems to be the simpler solution.

Comment: @Marijn This is just an example and I am often in a situation like this. As my documents contain a lot of pictures it is more convenient for me to create them separately.

Comment: Use `pdfcrop` on the pdf output. It trims all pages to the tight bbox of their content.

Comment: @AlexG `pdfcrop` seems to be an interesting option. Is there a way to execute `pdfcrop`  from the latex source file before each `\includegraphics`  if the pdf file has  changed ? I don't know if It is clear what I mean